# Web API with an invalid routes returns HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI 2 project using Attribute Routing and if an invalid route is requested then I receive a 404 with HTML in the body.  It is not even hitting my initial DelegatingHandler.  What do I need to do to make sure that all requests are processed thru the WebAPI.  This project has no MVC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the convention of using a web api is to consolidate data access into one point where your response type is matched with the request type. Something like application/json request results in a JSON Response. If an error should occure, it should still be passed as a JSON parsed message to the client. HTML Responses are a violation of the standard.

Comment: Agreed, WebAPI is returning the HTML from something that is occurring before it hits any code I have written.